# Change grouping separator in NumberFormat for Dart

Tags: dart, number-formatting

I have double value

```
double myNum = 110700.00;
```

I want to modify it's format using [NumberFormat](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html)

> 110 700

How it can be done?

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? Any error message?

Comment: I don't understand how can I set grouping separator that is now set to ","

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/dart-lang/intl#number-formatting-and-parsing ?

Comment: yes and still asking about setting grouping separator without changing locale

Answer (score 17):

You can't do it without changing locale because GROUP_SEP is final.

However, if you don't mind changing locale, which you can do on any particular instance, for example with `new NumberFormat('###,000', 'fr')` then pick any locale (e.g. French) which uses `non-breaking space` as the GROUP_SEP. Of course, you then end up with `,` as your decimal separator but if you don't ever use it then it's moot. That happens to work for the example in the question, but doesn't generalize.

It's possible (though fragile) to define your own language. So if you happen to be an English-speaking Australian who prefers `non-breaking space` as your group separator then define your own locale (e.g. `zz`)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/number_symbols_data.dart';
import 'package:intl/number_symbols.dart';

    main() {
      numberFormatSymbols['zz'] = new NumberSymbols(
        NAME: "zz",
        DECIMAL_SEP: '.',
        GROUP_SEP: '\u00A0',
        PERCENT: '%',
        ZERO_DIGIT: '0',
        PLUS_SIGN: '+',
        MINUS_SIGN: '-',
        EXP_SYMBOL: 'e',
        PERMILL: '\u2030',
        INFINITY: '\u221E',
        NAN: 'NaN',
        DECIMAL_PATTERN: '#,##0.###',
        SCIENTIFIC_PATTERN: '#E0',
        PERCENT_PATTERN: '#,##0%',
        CURRENCY_PATTERN: '\u00A4#,##0.00',
        DEF_CURRENCY_CODE: 'AUD',
      );

      print(new NumberFormat('###,000', 'zz').format(110700));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. You can also replace e.g. numberFormatSymbols['en'] using this scheme. And you could make it slightly more robust to changes in the original format by not hard-coding the values but referring to the one you were modifying. But the well-known locales don't change that often.

Answer (score 0):

For int you can also use the String utils to add spaces in the required frequency. It seems though as you cannot choose to count the letters from the right, thus you need to reverse the String twice.

```
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

String formatNumber(int number) {
   var s = StringUtils.reverse(number.toString());
   s = StringUtils.addCharAtPosition(s, " ", 3, repeat: true);
   return StringUtils.reverse(s);
}
```