# charts_flutter How to remove commas in y axis number values

Tags: flutter, charts

I am using [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) package. How can I remove those commas in y-axis values? For example, instead of `1,720` I want to have `1720`.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, they are [integer](https://github.com/google/charts/blob/master/charts_flutter/example/lib/axes/bar_secondary_axis.dart) values and you are looking for [turnOffGrouping](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/turnOffGrouping.html) method of `int`. Or, you can customize your `GROUP_SEP` by [declaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50142875/10659482) your own `NumberSymbols`.