# How to add space between numbers?

Tags: dart

Tell me how to split the number of spaces that appear between the numbers (1 000, 1 000 000, etc.). I understand that this should happen in a row and reverse it. then break the glue and turn over again. I just managed to expand. I can't figure out how to break it down. Or maybe there are some methods in the dart format like in others? In internet there are a lot of decisions for JavaScript or other languages which have Format methods. But I didn't find something for Dart.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
    var num = 123456789;
    var num1 = (num.toString()).split('').reversed.join();
    print(num1);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change grouping separator in NumberFormat for Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133321/change-grouping-separator-in-numberformat-for-dart)

Answer (score 4):

You should use regex to find three-digits and separate by a single space(' '). Here is an extension function (plus a working sample) to do that on any string containing numbers:

```
extension StringNumberExtension on String {
  String spaceSeparateNumbers() {
    final result = this.replaceAllMapped(
        RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), (Match m) => '${m[1]} ');
    return result;
  }
}

void main() async {
  print(
      'this is a number: 12345678901234567890123456789'.spaceSeparateNumbers());
}
```

Comment: ok. it works. thanks, but how write it without function

Comment: If you don't want to have an extension function, you can use 'replaceAllMapped' directly on the string. If want to work with a formatter, you can use 'intl' package.

Answer (score 1):

For formatting and localisation of currencies or quotes, prices and digits checkout [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and [NumberFormat class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html), because  I assume this is what you want to achieve. Different countries have different approaches for displaying numbers.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50142875/6229867) you have nice solution that works.

Comment: it cool but i can't to make format as i need from 1000 to 1 000.

Answer (score 0):

This function adds a space every 3 digits starting from the right:

```
String formatNumber(int number) {
    if (number == null) return '...'; //for those like me who don't use null-safety

    String result = '';
    int digit = 1; //to know when to add a space or not
    while (number > 0) {
      if (digit > 1 && digit % 3 == 1) //don't add a space at the very beginning
        result = (number % 10).toString() + ' ' + result;
      else
        result = (number % 10).toString() + result;

      digit++;
      number = number ~/ 10; //divides by 10, in other words, shifts 1 digit to the right
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String number(int number) {
    return NumberFormat.decimalPattern("uk-UA").format(number);
  }
```